# Why are All pins pull-up in SPARTAN 6?

Tags: spi, xilinx, jtag, spartan

When I programming SPI flash via SPARTAN 6 by Platform Cable USB II all FPGA pins (or almost) are HIGH state. Is it possible to change pins state to floating? Thanx.

Does anybody know How I can change the temporary core ( designed for program SPI flash via FPGA) or change any parameters for it? Needed Cores - xc6slx9_spi.cor, xc6slx16_spi.cor

There is solution for xc6slx45 - [look xc6slx45_float.**zip**](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/FPGA-Configuration/Request-Spartan-6-Pull-ups-during-SPI-indirect-programming-using/m-p/891949/highlight/true#M9900)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: I didn't find any information about it in datasheet (((

Comment: This problem only occurs when I am using external SPI flash programming. When the FPGA receives data from flash memory, this problem is not.

Comment: How's this a "problem"? Board has no configuration when it's switched on. Pins may be all inputs with pull ups. Its the same in embedded boards like arduino as well until it's configured as output pins.

Comment: This is a problem! Because FPGA is soldered and it drive different IC's! And when I want to change firmware I must desoldering some SMD components. All what I need it's that unused pins don't become HIGH state when I start programming SPI flash via FPGA.
P.C.: When board has no configuration all unused pins arn't in HIGH state.

Comment: And the console of ISE IMPACT contains the phrase: 
"SPI access core will be downloaded to the device to enable operations.
INFO:iMPACT - Downloading core file d:/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/spartan6/data/xc6slx45_spi.cor.".

Can I change some parameters of this core?

Comment: I think you don't understand. It depends on what configuration file is in FPGA when it boots up. You can configure each pin while you burn the bit file.

Comment: Mitu Raj, when I am programming SPI flash via FPGA and that FPGA is configured by core file (for example xc6slx45_spi.cor) all pins become HIGH state. How I can change propeties this core file or rewrite the core file?

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated pin that defines whether there is a pull-up on all pins during configuration or not: HSWAPEN.

The "Spartan-6 FPGA Configuration User Guide" UG380 contains all the details in plain text.

Comment: Sorry but it (HSWAPEN and others parameters) only for configuration FPGA by SPI flash. And when I am programming SPI flash via FPGA that HSWAPEN does not matter.